# Is it bad practice to use *str++?

Tags: c

Is it bad practice to use something like:

```
*str++;
```

vs

```
*str;
str++;
```

Where `str` is defined as `char str[];`?

Although they do the same thing, it seems like the first one may be more error prone, because doing something like `(*str)++` for example, leads to a compiler error, even though it *seems* like that's what we're doing.

Comment: `(*str)++ != *(str++)`

Comment: Do you know what `*str++` means? And do you expect consumers of your code to know?

Comment: @juanchopanza Yes. I understand that we dereference str and then increment the pointer. I was just wondering whether using *str++ is bad practice or not, since many answers I've seen here seem to use the second method.

Comment: I think you should read this: https://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/cpp/string/array-vs-ptr/ You should be careful with incrementing pointers anyway.

Comment: The point is that is is subtly complicated (de-reference has higher priority, but you are using post-fix increment). Personally, I would use `*(str++)` to be make the intent clear.

Comment: Without any additional context, I would say it is bad practice.

Answer (score 4):

By itself, it's not bad practice

The canonical definition of `strcpy` is something like

```
while ( *src )
  *dst++ = *src++;
```

You just want to be aware that it's really doing what you intend; you're obtaining the value pointed to by `str`, and as a *side effect* you're incrementing the pointer.

You also want to be aware of the difference between `*str++` and `(*str)++`; the second one increments the value that `str` points to, not `str` itself.

You also want to be aware that the side effect does not have to be applied immediately after the expression has been evaluated; it only has to be applied before the next *sequence point* (a point where all expressions have been evaluated and all side effects have been applied).  In the example above, both `dst` and `src` are incremented by the end of the statement, but it's not guaranteed that they are incremented in any particular order, or that they are incremented before or after the assignment takes place.  You want to avoid writing expressions like `*str = *str++`; the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 4):

`*str++` is idomatic. It's safe to expect programmers to know what it means without the parentheticals.

The notation has been around forever and was meant to be used.  From K&R:

> ```
> /* strcpy: copy t to s; pointer version 3 */
> void strcpy(char *s, char *t)
> {
>      while (*s++ = *t++)
>         ;
> }
> ```
>
> Although this may seem cryptic at first sight, the notational
>   convenience is considerable, and the idiom should be mastered, because
>   you will see it frequently in C programs.

Answer (score 2):

`*str++;` increments the `str` pointer. In C, array name is static pointer so you cannot increment it. And `(*str)++` increments value at index zero.

Comment: the only one who has mentioned that OP declared `char str[]`

Comment: great answer.. noone observed the OP part..

Answer (score 1):

It's not really bad practice, because it's heavily use in older code. As a personal opinion, I simply prefere be conservative about eventual readers that would not be expert on C operator priority (I admit I belong to that category ...)

So I almost always use parenthesis to disambiguate :

```
(*str)++;
```

But I only do that with true pointers and never with arrays, even if they are declared with unknown size, still to avoid possible mistakes when later maintening code.

So IMHO it is ok for

```
char *str;
```

but I would not use it for

```
char str[];
```

(what if I (or another programmer) later write `char str[SIZE]` ?)